# Cubase not remembering window position when switching apps and coming back to it

Tags: mojave

I know there's the ability to have "saved states" which is what Im' assuming Cubase (audio editing program) usually has, but for some reason I had an issue with Mojave recently, had to re-install the MacOS underlying, and now this program in particular is playing up.

So, I have 3 screens, I usually put one of these secondary windows on the 2nd screen, and normally if I switch to another app and come back to Cubase, everything's in it's place.

Now, every time I switch out and back, said window now reverts to the initial (1st) screen and doesn't remember its position.

There's no 'saved state' folder for the program, and I've reinstalled the software - is there any way of fixing this ? Or creating a saved state ? I don't have the programming knowledge.

Comment: Check System prefs>Mission Control & see what you have for 'displays have separate spaces'. My guess is you have that enabled. Cubase doesn't really use the Mac's Saved State because the state is really in the project file, or in your window sets, so I don't think it's the issue. I'm guessing it's because if each display is a different Space, you're moving one app to multiple Spaces… which isn't good. [Toggling that setting can really muck up your workflow & you have to re-allocate everything back to its correct Space, so I'm not going to do it just to test]

Comment: Excellent! Let me drop that into a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check System Prefs > Mission Control & see what you have for 'Displays have separate Spaces'.
My guess is you have that enabled.

Cubase doesn't really use the Mac's Saved State because the state is really in the project file, or in your window sets, so I don't think it's the issue. I'm guessing it's because if each display is a different Space, you're moving one app to multiple Spaces… which isn't good.

Toggling that setting can really muck up your workflow & you have to re-allocate everything back to its correct Space, so I'm not going to do it just to test ;)